# View doesn't show shadow on the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

It's a simple view in a FrameLayout. I need the FrameLayout for other views later. The code for the view:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/nav_style_start"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
  android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

The line `@drawable/nav_style_start` is necessary to add cornerRadius. The result:

[image]

Look at the bottom of the view, I can't see the full shadow. I've no idea why this happening, it's really weird.

Comment: For that you can use cardview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View` is getting clipped in the bottom. Just add a bit of margin to the bottom to make it visible.

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/nav_style_start"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
  android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

P.S - The same applies for the top.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:elevation="2dp"` with `app:elevation="2dp"`

It will work. and try with > 4dp for clear visible shadow.